# Cómo mover un sprite desde objeto 3D?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {

    }


    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            a = gameObject.transform.position.x;
        }

    }
}
```

En el código de arriba, mi intención es que

```
a = gameObject.transform.position.x;
```

ponga en *a* el valor de *x* del objeto que contiene el script, siendo *a* el *x* de otro objeto, para que ambos compartan *x* en cuanto el espacio sea presionado.
Mi duda es cómo referenciar el objeto cuya *x* es *a*, y a ser posible, en este mismo archivo C#.

No he añadido más código o detalles porque desde mi punto de vista no será de ayuda, o incluso les confundirá más a la hora de ayudarme. Si no es así, pregunten por información y daré lo mejor de mí en responder.

Answer (score 0):

Tras probar innumerables veces, doy con la respuesta, y la pongo aquí por si hay quien la necesite. El truco está en crear un objeto público que le haga referencia, y desde ahí aplicar la propiedad. Como en vez de con un Sprite yo trato con un *GameObject*, quedaría

```
public GameObject a;
```

Nótese que debe ser pública para poder editar su valor desde Unity. Una vez definido, para hacer cambiar la *x* con la del objeto que contiene el Script, escribimos

```
a.transform.position = new Vector3(gameObject.transform.position.x, 0, 0);
```

Ya que *gameobject* sigue haciendo referencia a éste, y a hace referencia a nuestro objeto de destino

Comment: Nota: en este script, a ya no es el valor de la x para el sprite, sino la referencia al sprite directamente, a la que cambiamos la propiedad de la coordenada x